# Django - Save Canvas object as a PDF-File to FileField

Tags: django, django-forms, reportlab

(How) is it possbile to save a canvas object as a PDF-file in a FileField ?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/outputting-pdf/#outputting-pdfs-with-django

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

class SomeView(FormView):

    form_class = SomeForm
    template_name = 'sometemplate.html'


    def form_valid(self, form):

        item = form.save(commit=False)

        # create PDF
        filename = "somefile.pdf"
        p = canvas.Canvas(filename)
        p.drawString(100, 100, "Hello world.")
        p.showPage()
        p.save()

        # this will not work, but i hope there is another way
        # Error: 'Canvas' object has no attribute '_committed'
        item.file = p

        # save form
        item.save()

        return super(SomeView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Traceback: (to long to paste all)

```
[...]

Exception Type: AttributeError at /return/
Exception Value: 'Canvas' object has no attribute '_committed'
```

If more information is need, please let me know!

Comment: Do you have the proper imports? i.e. `from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas` Post the traceback for the error you are receiving.

Comment: i added some more information

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def some_view(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.pdf"'

    p = canvas.Canvas(response)
    p.drawString(100, 100, "Hello world.")
    p.showPage()
    p.save()

    return response
```

Comment: This will return a HttpResponse (for download) and does not save the file in the models.FileField

Answer (score 0):

This is not ideal, but it works to to write the file (temporary) to disk and then save it in the FileField (The temporary file needs to be deleted after that, which is not in the code)

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from django.core.files import File
import codecs

class SomeView(FormView):

    form_class = SomeForm
    template_name = 'sometemplate.html'


    def form_valid(self, form):

        item = form.save(commit=False)

        # create PDF
        filename = "somefile.pdf"
        p = canvas.Canvas(filename)
        p.drawString(100, 100, "Hello world.")
        p.showPage()
        p.save()

        with codecs.open('somefile.pdf', "r",encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:   
           item.file.save('somefile.pdf',File(f))

        # save form
        item.save()

        return super(SomeView, self).form_valid(form)
```